# Answer no longer shows?

Tags: discussion, support

I had an 'answer' to question I posted (link below) and it's no longer showing. Is there anyway to know whether is this a result of the user deleting the answer and/or removal from admins. If it's the later, is there anyway to find out way why an answer has been removed.

[Seeking clarification on the use of “They/Them/Their” as a personal gender pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/513993/seeking-clarification-on-the-use-of-they-them-their-as-a-personal-gender-prono)

Comment: Can those that have down-voted please elaborate as to why this vote has been cast? What about my post is in violation of the community guidelines?

Comment: Relax, breathe in, everything is OK. The three downvotes on meta mean nothing. Seriously, nothing. Everyone, and I mean everyone, has had their share of downvotes, think of this as an initiation. Get through this period of awkwardness, you can overcome everything else but also enjoy the rewards even more because you rightfully earned them. Keep it light.

Comment: If it means nothing, then why do it? If no constructive feedback is given why isn t this feature removed? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Please don't be condescending either.

Comment: I'm saying not to take these downvotes seriously. There's just three, but if you continue to moan and gripe, users, the more experienced ones, will just be tempted to downvote. Just like I was when you told me not to be condescending. That wasn't very "nice" was it? Move on, think of answering some posts and earning some reputation points instead. Good luck :)

Comment: So you're saying up/down voting is essentially a popularity game?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there never was an answer on EL&U. The question was cross-posted on IPS and it has an  answer there. See [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99285/discussion-on-answer-by-tchrist-answer-no-longer-shows) for confirmation.

Comment: @NigelJ - No need for the rudeness.

Comment: @Cascabel - As this question is a non-question (it was an error on my part) I was hoping to delete the question, however  that is not allowed.

Comment: @DavidGalea There is no rudeness in my comment, at all. I am confident you are capable of attaining 'considerable up-voting'. And I am doing my best to encourage your efforts in that direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it happens, [that question has never received any answers whatsoever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElU0l.png), for there are zero deleted answers on the question [Seeking clarification on the use of “They/Them/Their” as a personal gender pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/513993/2085).  Why it should be axiomatically impossible to discover why something that never happened happened I shall have no choice but to leave as a possible exercise to the reader to discover on their own should they happen to be so inclined. :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99285/discussion-on-answer-by-tchrist-answer-no-longer-shows).

Comment: The Q was closed about the time this OP would have been answering; maybe he got caught out, or maybe just didn't check whether it was possible to answer before he tried.

Comment: @TimLymington If a question gets closed while you're posting an answer your answer will still go through, unless they've changed things recently.